# Opera Browser is downloading Youtube Video as File instead to load Flash

Tags: nginx, mime-types, plesk

I am setting up a Server with Nginx on a Managed Server without sudo rights but with Plesk 12.5

When I load a Page with iFrame embed Youtube Video than Opera is download a File called with the name of the URL. Youtube Video https://www.youtube.com/v/5eaR5WVCjOw is download as a File "5eaR5WVCjOw".

On Console I see the message:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/x-shockwave-flash: "https://www.youtube.com/v/5eaR5WVCjOw"

I thought adding "application/x-shockwave-flash swf;" will solve the problem but it still download a 5eaR5WVCjOw as file instead to load the flash.

Comment: It's Opera or YouTube problem. You can't fix it with your nginx (unless you own YouTube)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed this video with code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5eaR5WVCjOw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As here:

[image: plesk embed youtube video.png]

Opera version: 41.0.2353.57